# Rename multiple CSV Header to standard header using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have multiple csv file with same data but with different headers, I want to rename all CSV dataframe headers into standard headers, for example I have 1st dataframe with header - date, description, credit, debit, balance and 2nd dataframe with header - TXN date, description, withdrawl, deposit, total balance... now I want both the dataframes header as-  Txn Date, Description, Credit, Debit, Balance.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I'm understanding you correctly.  When you're reading the CSV into python. Use pandas read.csv() and make use of the usecol parameter to pass a list of strings that will be used as the column headers. EG

```
import pandas as pd

new_headers = ["date","description","credit","debit","balance"]
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", usecols = new_header)
print(df)
```

the result is

```
        date  description      credit         debit  balance
0   "test description"  test credit  test debit  test balance      NaN
1   "test description"  test credit  test debit  test balance      NaN
2   "test description"  test credit  test debit  test balance      NaN
3   "test description"  test credit  test debit  test balance      NaN
```